# How do i fix Runtime Error: Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compile requires ..... known to be compatibler?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, compiler-errors, android-jetpack-compose

Android compose project throw compilation error at RunTimme:

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.7.21 which is not known to be compatible. Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

I downgraded the version and expected it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned kotlin version to 1.6.10 and keep compose version to 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I faced error for days, This is what I did to fix this error:

1. Downgrade the Gradle version from id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false

To
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

2. I changed all the dependencies with $compose_version" to 1.3.2"

Example: Change implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version" to implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.2"